# How to adjust the scroll speed of UIScrollview in iOS swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I tried to set my own scroll speed using

```
self.scrollView.decelerationRate = .init(rawValue: 0.20)
```

But however this only controls the deceleration I want to reduce the scroll speed on drag itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I was able to make it by force stoping the scroll inside scrollViewDidEndDragging delegate by setting content offset of scrollview itself.

```
func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
        //check for scrollview status here
        if decelerate{
            self.scrollView.setContentOffset(self.scrollView.contentOffset, animated:false) // this will force stop the scrolling so that Drawable view can be added to pages
        }
    }
```